# Using Vue to enhance existing Multi page / server rendered / classic web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, server-rendering

I’v been searching for hours now and didn’t find anything close to my use case.

- I have a classic / multi page / server rendered e-commerce webstie made with JAVA
- I have a page where the server renders a list of products with a pagination
- Today, i use jQuery to do the pagination to give a better loading experience to the user
- On my server, if the request is AJAX a send a json response, else i render a normal html view
- With jQuery and vanilla it’s really easy, with Vue it doesn’t seem to work because Vue’s v-for and other template binding replaces the server rendered template directly…
- The server would render this :

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

article {
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!-- server rendered -->
<div id="app">
  <h2>Freelance list</h2>
  
  <article>
    <h3>louane</h3>
    <p>
      City : <strong>courbevoie</strong>
      <br> Phone : <strong>05-36-23-51-89</strong>
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>indra</h3>
    <p>
      City : <strong>rheden</strong>
      <br> Phone : <strong>(354)-415-2419</strong>
    </p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>angelo</h3>
    <p>
      City : <strong>montpreveyres</strong>
      <br> Phone : <strong>(883)-474-9314</strong>
    </p>
  </article>
  
  <a href="/prev-link">prev</a>
  <a href="/next-link">next</a>
</div>
<!-- server rendered -->
```

- I want to be able to do something like this but with Vue :

```js
// fake url link, normally this would be taken from the href or something
var url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=abc&results=3&page=';
var page = 1;
var $articles = $('.articles');
var tpl = $articles.children().eq(0).clone();

$('.prev').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  
  if (page <= 1) {
   return
  }

  page--;
  $.getJSON(url + page)
   .done(onReqDone);
});

$('.next').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

  page++;
  $.getJSON(url + page)
   .done(onReqDone);
});

function onReqDone(res) {
  $articles.html('');

  res.results.forEach(function(user) {
    var $node = tpl.clone();
    $node.find('h3').text(user.name.first);
    $node.find('strong:eq(0)').text(user.location.city);
    $node.find('strong:eq(1)').text(user.phone);
    $articles.append($node);
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  });

}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

article {
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- server rendered -->
<div id="app">
  <h2>Freelance list</h2>

  <div class="articles">
    <article>
      <h3>louane</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>courbevoie</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>05-36-23-51-89</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>indra</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>rheden</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(354)-415-2419</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>angelo</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>montpreveyres</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(883)-474-9314</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <a href="/prev-link" class="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="/next-link" class="next">next</a>
</div>
<!-- server rendered -->
```

Any ideo on how to do it ? Here are my tries :
https://jsfiddle.net/7270zft3/2/ : problem, it doesn’t remove the old dom

PS :
Before anyone talks about SSR with Vue ou just doing an SPA, here’s why i cant :

- This e-commerce website can’t be totally re made with a Single Page App, it will cost too much time and money for the benefit it would bring to us
- This e-commerce needs SEO to continue to drive traffic, just like any e-commerce btw
- If Vue can really be used like jQuery (this is why we bet on Vue), we should be able to do this without doing a full rewrite
- Event if we had time to rewrite an SPA, we can’t use SSR because our backend is made with JAVA and SSR seems to only be available with node and PHP with v8js module

Comment: It is removing the old dom elements for me. Except the first three you have hard coded.

Comment: "Except the first three you have hard coded" - that's the old dom lol, check the jQuery version to understand what i'm expecting.

Comment: I think you're basically looking for [hydration](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/hydration.html)

Comment: @RoyJ can you elaborate please. Just to be clear, what i need is the server to render actual data for a google-bot so as to have my SEO keep on, BUT because i don't want users to experience a full reload on each pagination, i handle paginagtion with ajax si i can't see where hydration comes in

Comment: Hydration is exactly that: you start with a server-rendered page that incorporates data. The initial state of the Vue matches the rendered page rather than replacing it, but all the Vue actions are made live, so that it can update the page according to user input. In your case, that would just make the pagination go live.

Comment: @RoyJ this seems to be what i'm looking for but how do you acheive this ? I assume you i would set a global data var hydrated with the same data i injected in my server template or something ? Could you give a fiddle ? Based on my fiddle

Comment: i think search page is not important in SEO because it change every time ... it's like the facebook feed it's not referenced in google ... what is important is the SEO of the product detail page of your ecommerce website ... this page must be loaded from the server

Comment: @Youssef of course it is lol and anyway the pagination here is just an example. Anyway I found a solution a mix between what somebody said here and something else

Comment: @darkylmnx can you put the final solution in your question ? I'm interested too in developping a hybrid approch between Single Page Application and Multi Page Application

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7270zft3/45/ @Youssef

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone on the Vue forum found a good approach close to what was posted here but suited better my need : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-vue-to-enhance-existing-multi-page-server-rendered-classic-web-app/30934/20

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a DOM ref to the server rendered content and then just as in jQuery, just clear the contents to the DOM element.

You need to perform this action only once, so you can may be add checks to see if your DOM ref is empty if `page === 1`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: null,
    page: 1
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: function(prev) {
      var page = this.page

      if (prev) {
        page--
      } else {
        page++
      }

      fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=abc&results=3&page=' + page)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.$refs.serverContent.innerHTML = '';
          this.users = data.results
          this.page = page
          window.scroll(0, 0)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

article {
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Freelance list</h2>
  <div ref="serverContent">
    <article>
      <h3>louane</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>courbevoie</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>05-36-23-51-89</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>indra</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>rheden</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(354)-415-2419</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>angelo</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>montpreveyres</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(883)-474-9314</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <!-- Vue part -->
  <!-- how to plug Vue to handle the pagination ? -->
  <article v-for="user in users">
    <h3>{{ user.name.first }}</h3>
    <p>
      City : <strong>{{ user.location.city }}</strong>
      <br> Phone : <strong>{{ user.phone }}</strong>
    </p>
  </article>
  <!-- Vue part -->

  <button v-show="page > 1" @click="loadData(true)">prev</button>
  <button @click="loadData()">next</button>
</div>
<!-- server rendered -->
```

But to do it Vue style, it is advised that you remove the rendering of first page from the server and let Vue handle data-fetching by itself so that Vue can use the `data` it stores as the source of truth instead of manipulating the DOM.

Comment: i think you didn't read enough my post, if i do it Vue style, then when a bot comes, he see's no data, so no SEO, sno less traffic, that's a problem i didn't have when using jQuery.

The goal is to have a server render the initial data for a bot and then just keep on with ajax

Comment: good solution though ta add a ref and empty it, i'll wait to see if anybody see's something else

Answer (score 1):

An example of [hydration](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/hydration.html). I wasn't able to get Vue to stop warning me that my generated HTML didn't match the original; it's not critical. In development, Vue will "bail and do a full render", but in production it will leave the pre-rendered. You just want to be sure they match, so that when it does update, it's what you expect.

I left jQuery in for the `getJSON`. Other than that, it's jQuery free.

```js
// fake url link, normally this would be taken from the href or something
var url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=abc&results=3&page=';
var page = 1;
$.getJSON(url + page).done((res) => {
  const articles = res.results;

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
  <div id="app">
    <h2>Freelance list</h2>
    <div class="articles">
      <article v-for="article in articles">
        <h3>{{article.name.first}}</h3>
        <p>
          City : <strong>{{article.location.city}}</strong>
          <br> Phone : <strong>{{article.phone}}</strong>
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <a href="/prev-link" class="prev" @click.prevent="--page">prev</a>
    <a href="/next-link" class="next" @click.prevent="++page">next</a>
  </div>
  `,
    data: {
      page,
      url,
      articles
    },
    methods: {
      getPage() {
        $.getJSON(this.url + this.page)
          .done((res) => {
            this.articles = res.results;
          });
      }
    },
    watch: {
      page() {
        this.getPage();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

article {
  margin: 8px 0;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" data-server-rendered="true">
  <h2>Freelance list</h2>
  <div class="articles">
    <article>
      <h3>louane</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>courbevoie</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>05-36-23-51-89</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>indra</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>rheden</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(354)-415-2419</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>angelo</h3>
      <p>
        City : <strong>montpreveyres</strong>
        <br> Phone : <strong>(883)-474-9314</strong>
      </p>
    </article>
  </div>

  <a href="/prev-link" class="prev">prev</a>
  <a href="/next-link" class="next">next</a>
</div>
<!-- server rendered -->
```

Comment: mmmh this adds lot's of template duplication mmmh because the markup here isn't the real markup of course so with the real markup this seems really messy... mmmmh and not so much maintainable

Comment: You have one template. You also have server-generated HTML. They have to match. There's no way around that. If you didn't have server-generated HTML, your template would be exactly the same. If you don't want to have a template, stick to manipulating the DOM with jQuery.

Comment: it's not that i don't want to have a template, it's that in your example, if ever my server template changes, i'll have to duplicate the change in the Vue template, that's the main problem here (it's not scalable).

Comment: You might want to look at [Vue on the server](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/universal.html) so that you could use the same template in both places.

Comment: i'll give it a look again (i already did for other use cases), i'd really like to see if Vue can replace jQuery for such basic use cases but it's seems way to complicated...